# pattern match failure in if condition

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to optimise pattern matching code. Old code has few patterns which were matched against an Id coming from the callback data.

```
var Id =  callbackData.Id

 var pattern1 = /gen/g;
 var pattern2 = /0--google/g;
 var pattern3 = /mail/g;

 var isPattern1 = pattern1.test(Id)
 var isPattern2 = pattern2.test(Id)
 var isPattern3 = pattern3.test(Id)

 if(Id && Id !== 0 && !isPattern1 && !isPattern2 && !isPattern3)
 {
   //return statement
   // function 
 } else {
   //return statement
   //function
 }
```

To optimise it I have created a json file which consists the patterns. Pattern are being read from the json file and matched with the Id.

```
Json file : test.json

{
  "PatternToSearch": {    
    "pattern1"  : "gen",
    "pattern2"  : "^0--google",
    "pattern3"  : "mail"
  }
}

var patternToMatch = require('test.json');
var patternArray = []; 
 Object.keys(patternToMatch.PatternToSearch).forEach(function (key) {
      var value = PatternToMatch.PatternToSearch[key];
      patternArray.push(value);
    });
return Promise.all(patternArray);
.then(patternArrayResult => {
  for (var val in patternArrayResult) {
    var pattern = patternArrayResult[val];
    var patternToCompare = new RegExp(pattern);
    var isPattern = patternToCompare.test(Id);
  }
})
```

I tried `forEach` as well but I am returning boolean value from the function and `forEach` doesn't return any value so I used for...in 
not able to replicate this condition `Id && Id !== 0 && !isPattern1 && !isPattern2 && !isPattern3`. How to do it?

Tried

```
if(isPattern){
  if(Id && Id !==0 && isPattern) {
    // return statement
  }
}
```

but this condition doesn't work when all the patterns don't match with Id. As I am this inside for loop only once this 
condition will be true and other times false which takes the controller in else loop
How to replicate the condition? (`Id && Id !== 0 && !isPattern1 && !isPattern2 && !isPattern3)`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you're using `Promise.all` -- are you doing any asynchronous operations?

Comment: I tried to return the value without using `Promise.all` but that's not working so used asynchronous approach. I recently started using promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns `true` if any item in an array causes a given function to return a truthy value:

```
return patternArray.some(v=>RegExp(v).test(Id));
```

And to include the value of `Id` in the test as well:

```
return Id && patternArray.some(v=>RegExp(v).test(Id));
```

You don't need to separately test `Id !== 0` because a zero value will already be treated as falsy value, causing the `&&` to short-circuit early. (So, `Id && Id !== 0` will only ever produce `0` or `true`: execution flow cannot ever reach the condition `Id !== 0` when that condition would be false, because the test `Id` for a zero value would have already terminated the `&&` flow early.)

Comment: `patternArray.some` is not working I have already tried using it earlier. It throws error `patternArray.some(...).then` is not a function. and I used `Id  !== 0` specifically as I am getting `Id` value as `0` sometimes

Comment: @Anju `patternArray.some(...).then` is indeed not a function. Why are you calling `.then` instead of simply returning the boolean result for `some`?

Comment: @Anju Regarding `Id`, I meant that the bare condition `Id` already does a superset of what `Id !== 0` does, so `Id !== 0` is redundant.

Comment: I just don't need the boolean result of `v=>RegExp(v).test(Id)` I need to return the boolean value from the function which would be called after the pattern matches or doesn't match at all.